# Why does realtime report show users but final report shows 0?

Tags: google-analytics

I have GA4 on a website. Before yesterday everything was working OK. Yesterday I switched on the "enhanced analytics" tracking and in today's report there are 0 users for yesterday. There are also 0 sessions etc, everything is 0 for yesterday (and today).

Yet realtime report works now and it also worked yesterday.
I switched off enhanced analytics, but nothing changed.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Turned out, there was just an unusually long delay. Data showed up after 48 hours.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it was a delay, the same thing happened to me and I can already see results for September 7 and 8.

Answer (score 0):

My reports have been showing 0 data for 2 weeks since I created the data stream. Only the Home Page shows users for the days and realtime continuously, but none of the subpage reports have any data. Excellent software!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).